# Redefinition error when trying to move class to a separate file

Tags: c++, class

I am trying to implement a class in c++ but I keep getting an error.
My .cpp looks like:

```
#include "medianfinderheader.h"
    MedianFinder::MedianFinder() { 
        }
        
    void MedianFinder::addNum(int num) {
        
    }
        
    double MedianFinder::findMedian() {
        double x=1.0;
        return x;
            
    }
```

while my header file looks like:

```
class MedianFinder {
public:
    MedianFinder() {};
    void addNum(int num) {};
    
    double findMedian() { 
        double x=1.0;
        return x;
        };
};
```

However I keep getting the following error :

```
g++ -I./ -g -Og -std=c++14   main.cpp MedianFinderClass.cpp -o medianEX
MedianFinderClass.cpp:2:5: error: redefinition of 'MedianFinder::MedianFinder()'
    2 |     MedianFinder::MedianFinder() {
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from MedianFinderClass.cpp:1:
medianfinderheader.h:3:5: note: 'MedianFinder::MedianFinder()' previously defined here
    3 |     MedianFinder() {};
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
MedianFinderClass.cpp:5:10: error: redefinition of 'void MedianFinder::addNum(int)'
    5 |     void MedianFinder::addNum(int num) {
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from MedianFinderClass.cpp:1:
medianfinderheader.h:4:10: note: 'void MedianFinder::addNum(int)' previously defined here
    4 |     void addNum(int num) {};
      |          ^~~~~~
MedianFinderClass.cpp:9:12: error: redefinition of 'double MedianFinder::findMedian()'
    9 |     double MedianFinder::findMedian() {
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from MedianFinderClass.cpp:1:
medianfinderheader.h:6:12: note: 'double MedianFinder::findMedian()' previously defined here
    6 |     double findMedian() {
```

I have no idea why this is happening when I've implmented classes like this before any help would be appreciated.
I have implemented classes in c++ in this exact same way, and I'm just really frustrated any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you need to add some header guards.

Answer (score 0):

this line

```
 void addNum(int num) {};
```

creates an implementation of addNum with an empty  body, you need

```
 void addNum(int num);
```

same for other functions in that class

Comment: thank you so much I have been beating my head against this for an hour.

Comment: You should add some header guards in there as well.